# Grid with content from Binding

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a library that generates a Grid based on input parameters. The Grid may contain different controls based on the input. I want to create a ListBox where each list item will get its own generated Grid. Is this doable? I couldnt find any Panel-derived (Gird, StackPanel etc) that expose the Content property like Button for example.

Answer (score 0):

How are you passing the data to build the Grid?

I'll assume you have a control that receives the data via a Dependency Property. I.e. you have something like MyControl.MyData property, where MyData is a Dependency Property. In that case, try using a DataTemplate.

Make an ObservableCollection where each item is the data you need to pass in order to build the grid.

On the instance of the ListBox, define ItemTemplate to use a DataTemplate consisting of your control.

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <myAssembly:MyControl MyData="{Binding }"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

@XAMeLi is almost right on the money with his answer - what would be better is a *[DataTemplateSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx#Styling_StyleSelection)*, that way each data item can have a different template (or generated grid). In your class that extends `DataTemplateSelector` you can easily generate or load the appropriate grid layout as either a separate control or as a dynamic DataTemplate.

Check this article for a good example: [WPF Tutorial - How To Use A DataTemplateSelector](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-how-to-use-a-datatemplateselector)